# How string buffer can lead to run malicious code?

Tags: c++, c, string, security, buffer

I have read at many places that string buffer overrun can create problems like adding malicious code or can be easily hacked. But string resides in BSS part and how it can affect code section.

Secondly, even if string is not overrunning, still it can be seen via hex editors, so can't they be equally dangerous?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) can occur on stack-allocated strings (e.g. unchecked call to `strcat` on a local `char buf[12]` array). This is why `sprintf` is deprecated, you should *always* use `snprintf`

It can be [exploited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploit_%28computer_security%29) by malicious code and [malware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware), e.g. [shellcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellcode)

<sup>Don't try to make some such malicious code: a teenager got prison for hacking and exploiting `sendmail` in the previous century.</sup>

<sup>BTW, a buffer overflow inside the heap can also give a lot of trouble, by corrupting unrelated data.</sup>